# Local html file on CD can open links with default program

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have a html file :

```
<a href="file:///C:/dbase.zip">test</a>

On chrome - when clicked the file downloaded to default directory
On IE - when clicked asks to open or download
```

how somehow when clicked, automatically open it with default program in windows

Comment: That's not possible due to security reasons.

Comment: This will be browser specific

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any references but i think youre not in controll of that behaviour. You can probably as well configure chrome the way it asks you before downloading and vice a verse configure IE to not ask but download the files in a certain directory.

Maybe there is a possiblity to have a java script code running on page load that initiates a download directly without any notification to the user but that wont run in any cases as well (since youre not in controll if someone switches off java script).